# How to import XML feed with multiple images

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml feed ...

```
<products>
  <product>
    <title>Mini Piscina</title>
    <description>Mini piscina penru copii pana la 6 ani.</description>
    <price>22.00</price>
    <images>
      <image1>produs_1402038969.jpg</image1>
      <image2>produs_1402382460.jpg</image2>
    </images>
  </product>
</products>
```

... and this part of script ...

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("../feed/feed") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$partener = 'toys';

foreach($xml -> product as $row) {
    $magazin = $partener;
    $titlu = $row -> title;
    $descriere = $row -> description;
    $pret = $row -> price;
    $imagine1 = $row -> images1;
    $imagine2 = $row -> images2;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO toys (magazin,titlu,descriere,pret,imagine1,imagine2)
            VALUES ('$magazin','$titlu','$descriere','$pret','$imagine1','$imagine2') ";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

... the result is: title, descrition and price are imported but image1 and images2 can not be imported.
Why? I'm a beginner. Please, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two images are not the children of product but its grandchildren. Simply, add the parent `images->` to the path to obtain their values:

```
foreach($xml -> product as $row) {
    $magazin = $partener;
    $titlu = $row -> title;
    $descriere = $row -> description;
    $pret = $row -> price;

    $imagine1 = $row->images->image1;
    $imagine2 = $row->images->image2;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO toys (magazin,titlu,descriere,pret,imagine1,imagine2)
            VALUES ('$magazin','$titlu','$descriere','$pret','$imagine1','$imagine2') ";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```